# get count of actions

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

i have nested dictionary like given below

```
{'C_Charges': {'Id': {'action': 'added',
          'new': '##########',
          'old': 'Null'},
         'P_Code': {'action': 'added', 'new': '#####', 'old': 'Null'}},
        'C_Insurance': {'Id': {'action': 'added',
          'new': '#######',
          'old': 'Null'},
         'Ins. Mode': {'action': 'added', 'new': 'Primary', 'old': 'Null'}},
        'C_Status': {'P_Status': {'action': 'Changed',
          'new': 'Waiting',
          'old': 'Blank'},
         'P_Status': {'action': 'Changed', 'new': 'New', 'old': 'Blank'}},
        '[P_Code': 'None'}]},{'C_Status': {'P_Status': {'action': 'Changed',
      'new': 'Blank',
      'old': 'New'}},
    'PTL Status': {'PTL File No': {'action': 'Changed',
      'new': '1',
      'old': '01'},
     'PTL Scan Date': {'action': 'Changed',
      'new': '07/17/2018',
      'old': '07/07/2018'}}},
```

what i want count of every action  like this 
where count = No repeatation

```
{'C_charges:ID:added':counts,
'C_charges:P_Code:added':counts,
'C_Insurance:id:added':counts,
'C_Insurance:Ins. Mode:added':counts,
'C_Status:P_status:changed':counts}
```

i am new to python so your help will beneficial and i am new to stack-overflow also so if have done editing mistake plz guide me

Comment: So, what would `counts` be here?

Comment: count = No repeatation

Comment: Your dictionary is invalid, it has duplicated keys.

Comment: it has duplicated keys but in nested dictionary

Comment: @benvc I just went to format this and noticed the same as you, you wouldn't by chance has finished formatting it properly have you?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede no, it is not clear to me what format the OP intends since there are duplicate keys in the outer `'C_Status'` dictionary and a set of square brackets half in and half out of a quoted string.

Comment: @benvc look at the formatting I just posted see if you think if we can use that at least as a template to come up with a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
some_dictionary = {
    'C_Charges': {
        'Id': {'action': 'added','new': '##########','old': 'Null'},
        'P_Code': {'action': 'added', 'new': '#####', 'old': 'Null'}
    },
    'C_Insurance': {
        'Id': {'action': 'added','new': '#######','old': 'Null'},
        'Ins. Mode': {'action': 'added', 'new': 'Primary', 'old': 'Null'}
    },
    'C_Status': {
        'P_Status': {'action': 'Changed','new': 'Waiting','old': 'Blank'},
        'P_Status': {'action': 'Changed', 'new': 'New', 'old': 'Blank'},
        'P_Code': {'None':'None'},
        'PTL Status': {
            'PTL File No': {'action': 'Changed','new': '1','old': '01'}
        },
        'PTL Scan Date': {
            'action': 'Changed','new': '07/17/2018', 'old': '07/07/2018'
        }
    }
}
```

This is for whoever is working on this code, I attempted to format the dictionary, I had to remove some duplicates and make a few assumptions due to the improper bracketing. I think we could still use this to come up with a solution that will work once OP has the proper dictionary setup.

If OP could look this over and comment what is missing or not desired, I will update.

Just assuming here, OP wants to find all `action` where the `value` is unique, so we would retrieve `added` and `Changed`, just attempting to piece this together, anyone feel free to chime in.

**Solution**

```
for k, v in some_dictionary.items():
    for a, b in v.items():
        if k == 'C_Status' and a == 'P_Code':
            continue
        elif a != 'PTL Status':
            status = [v for k, v in b.items() if k == 'action']
            status = ''.join(status)
            name = f"{k}: {a}: {status}" 
            actions = []
            actions.append(b.get('action'))
            actions = set(actions)
            count = 0
            for i in actions:
                count += 1
            print(f"{name}: counts: {count}")
        elif a == 'PTL Status':
            for e, f in b.items():
                status = [v for k, v in f.items() if k =='action'] 
                status = ''.join(status)
                name = f"{k}: {a}: {status}"
                actions= []
                actions.append(f.get('action'))
                actions = set(actions)
                count = 0 
                for i in actions:
                    count +=1
                print(f"{name}: counts: {count}")
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 dict.py
> C_Charges: Id: added: counts: 1
> C_Charges: P_Code: added: counts: 1
> C_Insurance: Id: added: counts: 1
> C_Insurance: Ins. Mode: added: counts: 1
> C_Status: P_Status: Changed: counts: 1
> C_Status: PTL Status: Changed: counts: 1
> C_Status: PTL Scan Date: Changed: counts: 1
> ```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I'll break down my method and show you how I approached it.  For this I'll be using the `dict.get()` function which you can read about here https://www.codzify.com/Python/python_dictionary.php

**Step One**

First lets take a look at how we can reach, each `action`
To do so we need to figure out which nested `dict`'s contain `action` for us to access properly

Let's run:

```
for k, v in some_dictionary.items():
    print(f"""
        {k}
        ---
        {v}

     """)
```

This returns:

```
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 dict.py

    C_Charges
    ---
    {'Id': {'action': 'added', 'new': '##########', 'old': 'Null'}, 'P_Code': {'action': 'added', 'new': '#####', 'old': 'Null'}}



    C_Insurance
    ---
    {'Id': {'action': 'added', 'new': '#######', 'old': 'Null'}, 'Ins. Mode': {'action': 'added', 'new': 'Primary', 'old': 'Null'}}



    C_Status
    ---
    {'P_Status': {'action': 'Changed', 'new': 'New', 'old': 'Blank'}, 'P_Code': {'None': 'None'}, 'PTL Status': {'PTL File No': {'action': 'Changed', 'new': '1', 'old': '01'}}, 'PTL Scan Date': {'action': 'Changed', 'new': '07/17/2018', 'old': '07/07/2018'}}
```

From here I can see that `action` represents a `key` located in another nested dictionary that is nested in `v`

So now we can look at `v` as a dictionary. Lets look at that using another for loop to print `key`'s and `value`'s for `v.items()`:

```
for k, v in some_dictionary.items():
    for a, b in v.items():
        print(f"""
            {a}
            ----
            {b}
            ---
        """)
```

This prints out:

```
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 dict.py

        Id
        ----
        {'action': 'added', 'new': '##########', 'old': 'Null'} 


        P_Code
        ----
        {'action': 'added', 'new': '#####', 'old': 'Null'}


        Id
        ----
        {'action': 'added', 'new': '#######', 'old': 'Null'}


        Ins. Mode
        ----
        {'action': 'added', 'new': 'Primary', 'old': 'Null'}


        P_Status
        ----
        {'action': 'Changed', 'new': 'New', 'old': 'Blank'}   


        P_Code
        ----
        {'None': 'None'}    


        PTL Status
        ----
        {'PTL File No': {'action': 'Changed', 'new': '1', 'old': '01'}} 



        PTL Scan Date
        ----
        {'action': 'Changed', 'new': '07/17/2018', 'old': '07/07/2018'}
```

Okay this is good now I can see `action` represents a `key` in `b` which is a dictionary, therefore I can use `b.get('action')` and get the proper value back.

Except for `PTL Status`, here I see the `key` is still deeper. If we look, its actually in a dictionary that is a `value` of a dictionary that is a `value` of `PTL Status` so I'm going to need to look at `PTL Status`'s `value` as a dictionary.

Lets try this:

```
for k, v in some_dictionary.items():
    for a, b in v.items():
        # later this will be b.get('action'), but hang on
        if a == 'PTL Status':
            for e, f in b.items():
                print(f)
```

And now we get:

```
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 dict.py
{'action': 'Changed', 'new': '1', 'old': '01'}
```

This tells me `action` is a `key` is in a dictionary `f` and I can get to it.
So I have a pathway to each `key` to apply `dict.get('key')` to, and get all the `values` I want

In practice those pathways look like this :

```
for k, v in some_dictionary.items():
    for a, b in v.items():
        if k == 'C_Status' and a == 'P_Code':
            continue
        elif a != 'PTL Status':
            b.get('action')
        elif a == 'PTL Status':
            for e, f in b.items():
                f.get('action')
```

The only addition to the code here was `if k == 'C_Status' and a == 'P_Code': continue` this is to ignore `P_Code` only for `C_Status` since it will return `None`.

**Step 2**

Our goal now is to count all of these unique `action`'s for each category.
In my head that means we have to create a list `actions` to `append` all the values for each loop, and make that a `set` so we dont't have duplicates. From there we have to count each `item` in that `set`. Let's see how we can do that:

```
for k, v in some_dictionary.items():
    for a, b in v.items():
        if k == 'C_Status' and a == 'P_Code':
            continue
        elif a != 'PTL Status':
            actions = []
            actions.append(b.get('action'))
            actions = set(actions)
            count = 0
            for i in actions:
                count += 1
        elif a == 'PTL Status':
            for e, f in b.items():
                actions = []
                actions.append(f.get('action'))
                actions = set(actions)
                count = 0
                for i in actions:
                    count += 1
```

Note that the use of `b.get` and `f.get` also I reset `actions = []` and `count = 0` at the beginning of each loop, since we don't need them for an running `count` of everything we want a `count` for each category individually.

**Step 3**

Last let's print everything with the proper format, by request:

```
{'C_charges:ID:added':counts,
'C_charges:P_Code:added':counts,
'C_Insurance:id:added':counts,
'C_Insurance:Ins. Mode:added':counts,
'C_Status:P_status:changed':counts}
```

Using this template, I try to get an idea of everything I'll need to `print` this format.

For `C_*Categories` I can just use the variable it's represented by in the `for` loops, which will be `k` in `some_dictionary.items()`, in each scenario.

For the subcategories `ID, P_Code, ...` I can use variable `a` from our `for a, b in v.items()`.

Now to get the word `added` or `changed` which I'm going to refer to as `status`(in retrospect should be something more like `state` to avoid confusion with `P_Status`), we are going to use a Dictionary Comprehension, explained in the link provided, thats going to look something like this:

```
status = [v for k, v in b.items() if k =='action']
```

and for `PTL Status`:

```
status = [v for k, v in f.items() if k == 'action']
```

When we print `status` its going to look like `['added']` but I just want `added` so I threw in a extra line:

```
status = ''.join(status)
```

I'm going to use the variables I have to construct a statement that I can print and store it as `name`, that looks like this:

```
`name = f"{k}: {a}: {status}"
```

Finally we can combine that with `count` and `print` a statement like this :

```
`print(f"{name}: counts: {count}")`
```

Putting it all together:

```
for k, v in some_dictionary.items():
    for a, b in v.items():
        if k == 'C_Status' and a == 'P_Code':
            continue
        elif a != 'PTL Status':
            status = [v for k, v in b.items() if k == 'action']
            status = ''.join(status)
            name = f"{k}: {a}: {status}" 
            actions = []
            actions.append(b.get('action'))
            actions = set(actions)
            count = 0
            for i in actions:
                count += 1
            print(f"{name}: counts: {count}")
        elif a == 'PTL Status':
            for e, f in b.items():
                status = [v for k, v in f.items() if k =='action'] 
                status = ''.join(status)
                name = f"{k}: {a}: {status}"
                actions= []
                actions.append(f.get('action'))
                actions = set(actions)
                count = 0 
                for i in actions:
                    count +=1
                print(f"{name}: counts: {count}")
```

Well I hope that helped I had to teach myself somethings to get it done, and I'm sure there is some one who can do this much better but this is what I got, Hope it helps!

Also I would take a look again at the dictionary provided, there are some things that just look odd like that `PTL File No` has an action but is nested in `PTL Status` which has no action but appears like `PTL File No` should have been on the same depth as `PTL Status`. Comment if you need anything I'll be around.

Comment: thanks @vash_the_stampede for formatting my dictionary plz can now give me solution of the problem

Comment: @MuhammadWaleed I actually didn't know how to accomplish this task when I formatted the dictionary, I was just hoping to help contribute for someone to solve this for you, but I just learned last night before I went to bed and put this solution  together for you

Comment: @MuhammadWaleed Also make sure to update your dictionary so that `C_Status: {'P_Code'} : {'None':'None'}`

Comment: @MartinR, is this better? Trying, looking for input to improve my responses.